# Dynamic Rows Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I have a decent sized form on my website which has an insert row button at the bottom, this adds rows to the bottom of the form to which I can also click the corresponding delete button to delete that single row to.

Screenshot of the bottom of the form

[image]

Now, the issue arises when I click the "Send" button. If I have added a few rows to the form and then click the "Send" button, the rows disappear from the form and so do their values. I want it so once I've added the rows and click the send button, the form keeps its state properly and keeps the rows that I previously added.

HTML Code can be found here:

```
<form name="contact" action="request-a-quote.php" method="POST">
  <table class="form">
    <thead>
      <?php if (isset($form_error_message)) { echo $form_error_message; } ?>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Company Information</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Company Name *</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="company_name" type="text" <?php if ($error_company_name=='Y' ) { echo 'class="error_on_field"'; } ?>
          <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Company Name"'; } ?> maxlength="45" value="
          <?php if (isset($company_name)) echo $company_name; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Contact Information</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Contact person name *</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="contact_person_name" type="text" <?php if ($error_contact_person_name=='Y' ) { echo 'class="error_on_field"'; } ?>
          <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Contact Person Name"'; } ?> maxlength="45" value="
          <?php if (isset($contact_person_name)) echo $contact_person_name; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Contact person e-mail *</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="contact_person_email" type="email" <?php if ($error_contact_person_email=='Y' ) { echo 'class="error_on_field"'; } ?>
          <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Contact Person Email"'; } ?> size="40" value="
          <?php if (isset($contact_person_email)) echo $contact_person_email; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Contact address *</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="contact_address" type="text" <?php if ($error_contact_address=='Y' ) { echo 'class="error_on_field"'; } ?>
          <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Contact Address"'; } ?> maxlength="45" value="
          <?php if (isset($contact_address)) echo $contact_address; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Contact person phone *</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="contact_person_phone" type="text" <?php if ($error_contact_person_phone=='Y' ) { echo 'class="error_on_field"'; } ?>
          <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Contact Person Phone"'; } ?> maxlength="45" value="
          <?php if (isset($contact_person_phone)) echo $contact_person_phone; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Boiler Information</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Boiler brand / manufacturer *</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="boiler_brand_manufacturer" type="text" <?php if ($error_boiler_brand_manufacturer=='Y' ) { echo 'class="error_on_field"'; } ?>
          <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Boiler brand / Manufacturer"'; } ?> maxlength="45" value="
          <?php if (isset($boiler_brand_manufacturer)) echo $boiler_brand_manufacturer; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Average annual fuel consumption (kW or £)</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="average_annual_fuel_consumption" type="text" <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Average annual fuel consumption (kW or £)"'; } ?> size="60" value="
          <?php if (isset($average_annual_fuel_consumption)) echo $average_annual_fuel_consumption; ?>" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Current cost per kW (Pence)</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="current_cost_per_kw" type="text" <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Current cost per kW (Pence)"'; } ?> size="60" value="
          <?php if (isset($current_cost_per_kw)) echo $current_cost_per_kw; ?>" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Type of fuel</th>
        <td colspan="2">
          <select name="type_of_fuel">
                                            <option value="0">Please Select...</option>
                                            <option <?php if ($type_of_fuel == "Gas") echo "selected=selected" ?>>Gas</option>
                                            <option <?php if ($type_of_fuel == "Oil") echo "selected=selected" ?>>Oil</option>
                                            <option <?php if ($type_of_fuel == "LPG") echo "selected=selected" ?>>LPG</option>
                                            <option <?php if ($type_of_fuel == "Other") echo "selected=selected" ?>>Other</option>
                                        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Boiler Capacity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Type of boiler</th>
        <td colspan="2">
          <select name="type_of_boiler">
                                            <option value="0">Please Select...</option>
                                            <option <?php if ($type_of_boiler == "Thermostatically Controlled") echo "selected=selected" ?>>Thermostatically Controlled</option>
                                            <option <?php if ($type_of_boiler == "CHP") echo "selected=selected" ?>>CHP</option>
                                            <option <?php if ($type_of_boiler == "Steam") echo "selected=selected" ?>>Steam</option>
                                        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Total capacity</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="total_capacity" type="text" <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Total Capacity"'; } ?> size="60" value="
          <?php if (isset($total_capacity)) echo $total_capacity; ?>" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="desktop_only">Boiler capacity</th>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="boiler_capacity" type="text" <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Boiler Capacity"'; } ?> size="60" value="
          <?php if (isset($boiler_capacity)) echo $boiler_capacity; ?>" ></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Required Measurements (up to 4 meters)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="row">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="center">
          <img src="images/required-measurements.jpg" alt="Required Measurements" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="addrows">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Circumference</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="row">
      <tr>
        <th>Measurement 1</th>
        <td><input name="circumference_1" type="text" <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Circumference 1"'; } ?> size="60" value="
          <?php if (isset($circumference_1)) echo $circumference_1; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input name="length_1" type="text" <?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo 'placeholder="Length 1"'; } ?> size="60" value="
          <?php if (isset($length_1)) echo $length_1; ?>" ></td>
        <td style="width:200px;"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p><input type="button" id="insert_row" value="Insert row"></p>
  <script>
    $('#addrows').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })
    $('p input[type="button"]').click(function() {
      $('#addrows').append('<tr><th>Measurement 2</th><td><input type="text" class="fname" /></td><td><input type="text" class="fname" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td></tr>')
    });
  </script>
  <table class="form">
    <tr id="send_holder">
      <td class="calculate" colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

PHP Code can be found here:

```
<?php
// Taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - Example #4 Sending HTML email
// PHP script triggers if SEND button has been clicked
if  (isset($_POST['submitted']))    {

    // Set up Fasthosts mandatory settings to enable email sending
    $email_from = 'EMAIL';          // Must be an email set-up in Fasthosts, mailbox or forwarder 
    ini_set('SMTP','smtp.fasthosts.co.uk' );
    ini_set('sendmail_from', $email_from);
    $website_name = 'NAME';                     // Change to the name of the website in which the form is
    $form_name = 'Request a Quote';                         // Change to the name of the form

    // Populate PHP variables from $_POST array
    $company_name                       = htmlentities(trim($_POST['company_name']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $contact_person_name                = htmlentities(trim($_POST['contact_person_name']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $contact_person_email               = htmlentities(trim($_POST['contact_person_email']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $contact_address                    = htmlentities(trim($_POST['contact_address']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $contact_person_phone               = htmlentities(trim($_POST['contact_person_phone']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $boiler_brand_manufacturer          = htmlentities(trim($_POST['boiler_brand_manufacturer']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $average_annual_fuel_consumption    = htmlentities(trim($_POST['average_annual_fuel_consumption']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $current_cost_per_kw                = htmlentities(trim($_POST['current_cost_per_kw']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $type_of_fuel                       = htmlentities(trim($_POST['type_of_fuel']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $type_of_boiler                     = htmlentities(trim($_POST['type_of_boiler']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $total_capacity                     = htmlentities(trim($_POST['total_capacity']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $boiler_capacity                    = htmlentities(trim($_POST['boiler_capacity']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $circumference_1                    = htmlentities(trim($_POST['circumference_1']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");
    $length_1                           = htmlentities(trim($_POST['length_1']),ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-15");

    // Check for errors and update error variables, e.g. $error_on_name, etc.
    if  (empty($company_name)) { $error_company_name = 'Y'; }
    if  (empty($contact_person_name)) { $error_contact_person_name = 'Y'; }
    if  (empty($contact_person_email)) { $error_contact_person_email = 'Y'; }
    if  (empty($contact_address)) { $error_contact_address = 'Y'; }
    if  (empty($contact_person_phone)) { $error_contact_person_phone = 'Y'; }
    if  (empty($boiler_brand_manufacturer)) { $error_boiler_brand_manufacturer = 'Y'; }

    $errors_exist = $error_company_name.$error_contact_person_name.$error_contact_person_email.$error_contact_address.$error_contact_person_phone.$error_boiler_brand_manufacturer;

    // No errors exist - Set up and send emails and redirect
    if  (!empty($errors_exist)) {
            $form_error_message = '<tr><td colspan="2"><p id="form_error_message">There are a few pieces of information that we need from you before this form comes through to us. They are highlighted below in red, so please fill those in again and click the <strong>Submit</strong> button again.</p></td></tr>';
        // Else, i.e. if $errors array is empty
        }   else    {

        // Set up email recipient(s)
        $to1 = $contact_person_email;                       // First email is sent to the person who submitted the form; $email
        $to2 = 'email_address';             // Second email is sent to the website owner; change this to the relevant email address

        // Set up email subject(s)
        $subject1 = 'Thanks for your submission - '.$website_name.' - '.$form_name.' form'; // Do not change
        $subject2 = 'Website submission - '.$website_name.' - '.$form_name.' form';         // Do not change

        // Set up email message(s)
        $message1 = '
        <div style="font-family: arial, tahoma, sans serif; font-size: small; color: #666;">
            <p>Hi '.$contact_person_name.',</p>
            <p>Thanks for completing our '.$form_name.' form on the '.$website_name.' website. We\'ll be in touch as soon as we can!</p>
            <p>With kind regards<br />'.$website_name.'</p>
        </div>';
        $message2 = '
        <div style="font-family: arial, tahoma, sans serif; font-size: small; color: #666;">

            <p>The following submission has been made via the '.$form_name.' form:</p>
            <h2>Company Information</h2>
            <p>Company Name: '.$company_name.'</p>
            <h2>Contact Information</h2>
            <p>
                Contact Person Name: '.$contact_person_name.'
                <br />Contact Person Email: '.$contact_person_email.'
                <br />Contact Address: '.$contact_address.'
                <br />Contact Person Phone: '.$contact_person_phone.'
            </p>
            <h2>Boiler Information</h2>
            <p>
                Boiler Brand/Manufacturer: '.$boiler_brand_manufacturer.'
                <br />Average Annual Fuel Consumption: '.$average_annual_fuel_consumption.'
                <br />Current Cost per kW: '.$current_cost_per_kw.'
                <br />Type of Fuel: '.$type_of_fuel.'
            </p>
            <h2>Boiler Capacity</h2>
            <p>
                Type of Boiler: '.$type_of_boiler.'
                <br />Total Capacity: '.$total_capacity.'
                <br />Boiler Capacity: '.$boiler_capacity.'
            </p>
        </div>';

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        // Additional headers can be set here; Change From to website owner
        $headers .= 'From: NAME <' . $email_from . '>' . "\r\n";

        // Send emails
        mail($to1, $subject1, $message1, $headers);
        mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers);

    // Errors exist - populate $form_error_message ready for output to browser
    }   

}   // END-OF-IF (isset($_POST['submitted']))

//  Stage M3. Add <p> to end of $form_error_message
    $form_error_message = $form_error_message.'</p>';
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with javascript. You might also want read [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use the `.on` method when you add to the table and the new rows will get recognised

Comment: @RiggsFolly Could you please demo this to me?

Comment: You already did it in the line above.. here `$('#addrows').on('click',.....`

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's in the line above yes, however it's not on the add rows button. How would I add the .on method when .append is there already?

Answer (score 1):

Once you're doing a form submit (instead of an Ajax call) it's pretty easy.

In your form:

```
<input type="text" name="measure[]" value="This input is fixed">
```

Each time you add a new input (from the group "measure") it should has the same name as an array: `name="measure[]"` like the input above.

Then in PHP you just need to run into this array to get all fields.

```
<?php
$total_elements = count($_POST['measure']);
for ( $i=0;$i<$total_elements;++$i ) {
  echo $_POST['measure'][$i];
}
?>
```

Hope it helps.